# Is there a plan to support HP x360 Spectre 2-in-1 laptop?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hp

I tried dual booting Ubuntu with windows on the HP Spectre 2-in-1. Currently, I am having issues with freezing when I boot into Ubuntu, sometimes I can get past the login screen, other times I can't. Initially, there is no support for wifi either. Are there plans to officially support the laptop or fixing these bugs without installing a new kernel?

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2407615

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? And often bugs are fixed but only in newer kernel for new hardware.  There seem to be a lot of x360 threads all with various fixes. Are there a lot of different configurations of rx360. Some say Intel and others Ryzen. And fixes then would be significantly different.

Comment: I haven't tried updating UEFI. Do you think that these issues would be fixed on newer versions of Ubuntu? I haven't ever put a newer kernel on a linux machine.

Comment: I always recommend UEFI updates. Almost all systems need UEFI updates, anyway, for mitigation of Meltdown and Spectre CPU vulnerabilities from cpu speculative execution and caching. Both Windows & Linux have updated kernels but some of those updates also need UEFI update. If newer Ryzen based you have to have an UEFI update as AMD released major fix and then vendors started to add those fixes last fall in UEFI updates.

Comment: my last BIOS update for my HP ENVY x360 - 15m-bq121dx was 21 July 2019, rev21... (I had a hell of a year with this thing last year). I still cannot suspend without losing USB and occasional lockups. So it has not fixed all issues. I assume that UEFI and BIOS mean much the same thing.. correct me if I am wrong.